# Laravel 5.3 customizing registration form

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I have setup default authentication that comes with laravel out of the box. Since that form requires from the user in order to registrate confirm password and name, which I would like to remove I wonder where can I remove those fields, since I can just remove them from the form, because then I get errors.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ducan.namirnicama@gmail.com,
>   $2y$10$rr8IQ5xwCJR8DuCXQbw/FenYrK/HcAtAk0br5OZF6ZSW2l21MxrsS,
>   2016-11-22 13:59:55, 2016-11-22 13:59:55))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to go your user migration `database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` and either remove the `name` line or change it to be nullable i.e.

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Then go to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` and you should be able to see a `validator()` method and a `create()` method. You will need to remove the `name` lines in each.

Hope this helps!